# Setup Android System Alarm Clock with custom Ringtone and with Vibrate on/off programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm

I need to test the different Alarm ringtones put I need it to be automated.

How can I set my own Alarm Ringtone and vibration settings programmatically?

```
public void ringAlarm(int addtime){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent openNewAlarm = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    openNewAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    openNewAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+addtime);
    openNewAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI,true);
    startActivity(openNewAlarm);


}
```

I'm Testing it like this. But I need completely different ringtone for every alarm not just setting up the default one.

```
public void testAlarmStock(){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://media/internal/audio/media/54");
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(mContext, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, uri);
    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    mActivity.ringAlarm(1);

}
```